# make a change on the string based on mapping

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have the following string format

```
str="aaa.[any_1].bbb.[any_2].ccc"
```

I have the following mapping

map1:

```
any_1 ==> 1
cny_1 ==> 2
```

map2

```
any_2 ==> 1
bny_2 ==> 2
cny_2 ==> 3
```

What's the best command to execute on the `str` with taking account the above mapping in order to get

```
$ command $str
aaa.1.bbb.1.ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn your `map` files into `sed` scripts:

```
 sed 's%^%s/%;s% ==> %/%;s%$%/g%' map?
```

Apply the resulting script to the input string. You can do it directly by process substitution:

```
sed 's%^%s/%;s% ==> %/%;s%$%/g%' map? | sed -f- <(echo "$str")
```

Output:

```
aaa.[1].bbb.[1].ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

*Update: I now think that I didn't understand the question correctly, and my solution therefore is wrong. I'm leaving it in here because I don't know if parts of this answer will be helpful to your question, but I encourage you to look at the other answers first.*

Not sure what you mean. But here's something:

```
any_1="1"
any_2="2"
str="aaa.${any_1}.bbb.${any_2}.ccc"
echo $str
```

The curly brackets tell the interpreter where the variable name ends and the normal string resumes. Result:

```
aaa.1.bbb.2.ccc
```

You can loop this:

```
for any_1 in {1..2}; do
    for any_2 in {1..3}; do
        echo aaa.${any_1}.bbb.${any_2}.ccc
    done
done
```

Here `{1..3}` represents the numbers 1, 2, and 3. Result

```
aaa.1.bbb.1.ccc
aaa.1.bbb.2.ccc
aaa.1.bbb.3.ccc
aaa.2.bbb.1.ccc
aaa.2.bbb.2.ccc
aaa.2.bbb.3.ccc
```

Comment: Why the loop ? there's 2 maps with different keys (any, bny, cny)

Comment: I don't see how this is in any way applicable to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 echo "${str}"
 cat Map1
 cat Map2
} | sed -n '1h;1!H;$!d
x
s/[[:space:]]*==>[[:space:]]*/ /g
:a
s/\[\([^]]*\)\]\(.*\)\n\1 \([^[:cntrl:]]*\)/\3\2/
ta
s/\n.*//p'
```

- you could use several mapping, not limited to 2 (even and find to cat every mapping found).
- based on fact that alias and value have no space inside (can be adapted if any)

Answer (score 0):

I have upvoted @chw21's answer as it promotes - right tool for the problem scenario. However,

You can devise a `perl`based command based on the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = join '',<DATA>;
my %myMap = (
 'any_1' => '1',
 'any_2' => '2'
);

$text =~s/\[([^]]+)\]/replace($1)/ge;

print $text;

sub replace {
 my ($needle) = @_;
 return "\[$needle\]" if ! exists $myMap{ lc $needle};
 return $myMap{lc $needle};
}

__DATA__
aaa.[any_1].bbb.[any_2].ccc
```

Only thing that requires a bit of explanation is may be the regex,it matches text that comes between square brackets and sends the text to replace routine. In replace routine, we get mapped value from map corresponding to its argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="."
    m["any_1"]=1; m["cny_1"]=2
    m["any_2"]=1; m["bny_2"]=2; m["cny_2"]=3
    for (i in m) map["["i"]"] = m[i]
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        $i = ($i in map ? map[$i] : $i)
    }
    print
}
$ awk -f tst.awk <<<'aaa.[any_1].bbb.[any_2].ccc'
aaa.1.bbb.1.ccc
```